# Beginner React Problem - problems with import

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am beginner user and am following along with a Scrimba tutorial on how to use react. Essentially, the tutorial began with directly using the React external library (unpkg.com...) but then switched to dependencies. I am using WebStorm.

So, I modified my code to include import statements and removed the script src tags in my original HTML file. However, once I did this I began to receive the classic `"SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"`. After researching online, I added the "type" : "module" line to my package.json file. However, after doing that, it seems that my .js file is no longer operating with React. I get a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`. Clearly, the IDE doesn't like the html bracket in the JS file. Below is code snippet of my html, js, and package.js file respectively:

```
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello</h1>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```
"type": "module",
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
}
```

I know this might seem like a very basic question, but I've spent hours and I cannot seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It would be far easier to get up and running with something like [vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/) which does all the necessary scaffolding for you, and which works.

Answer (score 1):

You are using React version 18 but to render you are using **ReactDOM.render(Hello, document.getElementById("root"))** which was used till React version 17. React version 18 own wards the syntax changed to **ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render()**, so you just need to replace **render** function with the newly **createRoot** function. For more info check [this](https://efficientuser.com/2022/10/07/reactdom-render-is-no-longer-supported-in-react-18/#:%7E:text=The%20render()%20method%20of,and%20creates%20a%20React%20root.). Either change react version to 17 as
Scrimba is using version 17 in the course I am referring, or change the rendering method to that of version 18.

Comment: Even after using the new syntax, it still returns the Unexecpted token '<' error:

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<h1>Hello</h1>)
returns SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'